# How to configure Jenkins to run 1 selenium test case

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, surefire

I am running Jenkins on Windows 7 as service.

I have approximately 100 selenium test cases in package, but I want to run only 1 test case.

Is it possible to configure Jenkins to run not all, but 1 test?

Comment: Is Jenkins triggering the tests through maven? Are you using the surefire plugin?

Comment: Please provide further information on how you invoke these tests right now, and what your environment is.

Comment: Yes, Jenkins triggering the tests through maven and I am using the surefire plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your Jenkins build is configured, somewhere you are specifying the maven goals. These can be configured to specify the test you want to execute, as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html):

> mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test

Note that this require surefire 2.7.3 or later, and Junit 4.X or TestNG:

> As of Surefire 2.7.3, you can also run only a subset of the tests in a test class.
>
> NOTE: This feature is supported only for Junit 4.x and TestNG.

For older versions of the Surefire plugin/JUnit, it seems it is only possible to control this on class level, i.e. you cannot specify a specific test in a class:

> mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test